# c# override Generic BaseMethod of other type

Tags: c#

#### Problem

Im inheriting a generic Type `DoSome<T>`, and creating the new Type `DoSomeList<T>`. `DoSome<T>` implements `IDo<T>` which provides the `Task DoSomething(T input)` Method. I now want to override `DoSomeList<T>.DoSomething()` to call the base Method in a foreach loop, because, it is to be called with a list.

Here is my Code:

```
public interface IDo<T>
{
    Task DoSomething(T input);
}

public class DoSome<T> : IDo<T>
{
    protected virtual async Task DoSomething(T input)
    {
        // Does something
    }
}

public class DoSomeList<T> : DoSome<T> where T: List<T>
{
    protected override async Task DoSomething(T input)
    {            
        foreach (var item in input)
        {
            await base.DoSomething(item);
        }
    }
}
```

however, when I try to set up DI, with the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` Framework, I get a Compile error:

```
private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    serviceCollection.AddTransient<IDo<List<SomeType>>, DoSomeList<SomeType>>(); // Compile Error here
}
```

> 'DoSomeList<SomeType>' cannot be used as type parameter 'TImplementation' in the generic type or method 'ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddTransient<TService, TImplementation>(IServiceCollection)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'DoSomeList<SomeType>' to 'IDo<System.Collections.Generic.List<SomeType>>'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
public class DoSomeList<T, TBase> : DoSome<TBase>, IDo<T> where T : List<TBase>
```

That way, the base-method is `TBase` and can be called in the foreach loop. Of course, there's wrapping used instead of overriding.

And in DI its registred like that:

```
private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    serviceCollection.AddTransient<IDo<List<SomeType>>, DoSomeList<List<SomeType>, SomeType>>()
}
```